# A simple dividation problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

I can solve the below question by putting the each possibility into the questions conditions but I want to find out the value without putting the possibility .

The number m yields a remainder p when divided by 14 and a remainder q when divided by 7.
 If p = q + 7, then which one of the following could be the value of m ?

(A) 45
(B) 53
(C) 72
(D) 85
(E) 100

Comment: Just try all 4 possibilities, calculate the remainder of 45/14, 45/7, 53/14, ...

Answer (score 1):

Since p = q + 7, the quickest way is to find the remainder p, if it is less than 7, remove the choice, if p is equal to or greater than 7 and less than 13 then check q. And, there is no unique solution!